# If and Page.Should have_css in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement, ab-testing

I am a newbie in Ruby and I have a problem with if condition and page.should have when I programmed the A/B Test for log in function.

This is my code:

```
if (page.should have_css("body.bg-b")) || (page.should have_css("body.bg-c")) 
    #do something           
else
    #do something
end
```

It works fine in the if condition. My problem is in the case the page doesn't have bg-b or bg-c, it should go to else condition, right, but it stopped running and said

> Capybara::ExpectationNotMet:
>     expected to find css "body.bg-b" but there were no matches

Is there something wrong with this code?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword "should" seems you're asserting something.

If you simply want to make a IF, you should write something like this :

```
if (page.has_css?("body.bg-b")) || (page.has_css?("body.bg-c")) 
   # Check something with should
else
   # Check something else with should
end
```

It you want to check the page have a css or the other one, you should write

```
(page.has_css?("body.bg-b")) || (page.has_css?("body.bg-c")).should == true
```

Or

```
if !page.has_css?("body.bg-b")
  page.should have_css("body.bg-c")
end
```

Comment: they should all be `has_css?`, not `have_css?`. But the idea is right.

Comment: @sevenseacat Sure, I don't use this syntax. I correct it.

Comment: @ForgetTheNorm: thanks man, it worked for me, page.has_css?, this is what I need for my automation test.